# Restore MacBook AIr (mid 2011) partitions

Tags: bootcamp, startup, partition

I just messed up my partions on my harddisk.

The situation:

Installed windows 7 using bootcamp (NTFS).
After that i wanted to ceate a shared partition, on wich both MAC OS and Windows can write.
In windows 7 Disk Management i took 5 GB off the Bootcamp partion, and created a FAT32 partion from it.

Now when i boot only the windows partition is visible when i reboot (no macosx or restore) When i try to start windows it gives a short BSOD (acnt read t) and then reboots again.

I guess i should create some sort of bootable restore USB stick.
Any ideas how to get me going again ....please....

Answer (score 1):

Hold down Command+R while booting it, and it should run Lion Recovery, either from your recovery partition if it still exists or directly over the Internet. See [here](http://www.apple.com/macosx/recovery/) for details.

Comment: Thanx didnt know this! I ended up creating a bootable USB drive and used TestDisk to recover the partition table. at least the MacOSx and the recovery disk work again.Only thing is i cant startup from the Bootcamp partition. Still working on that.